# Connection issue from Spring Boot projects to PostgreSQL database while connecting

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am working on a micro service oriented multi-tenant application using Spring MVC, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL. In my service domain, I have different 30 number of Spring Boot projects connecting with same database.

**Issue**

When I am starting more than 11 Spring Boot project parallel, I am not able to retrieve data from database. I am only getting blank JSON response. But If I am starting only less than 11 projects, then at that time, I am able to get the micro service result. Problem getting when I am starting from 12th service.

**Troubleshooting and my Investigation**

According to reading, I made little bit changes as follows,

I set PostgreSQL config file, `max_connections = 100` and `shared_buffers = 128MB`.

But that not solved my problem. And also added additional lines in my `application.property` for `hikari` connection pool like the following,

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=3
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=3
```

Even this also not fixing my issue. Still I am only able to start maximum 12 Spring Boot projects at one time.

On pom.xml added the following,

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

application.property updated with the following,

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

**Updates**

As I mentioned above, in total I have 100 max connection. When I am starting first microservice and monitoring the DB connection by querying (below query), I am getting 10 connections.

```
select max_conn,used,res_for_super,max_conn-used-res_for_super res_for_normal 
from 
 (select count(*) used from pg_stat_activity) t1,
 (select setting::int res_for_super from pg_settings where 
  name=$$superuser_reserved_connections$$) t2,
 (select setting::int max_conn from pg_settings where 
 name=$$max_connections$$) t3
```

Activity screenshot - When I started only 1 microservice I am getting like these,

[image]

Activity screenshot 2:

[image]

So here, for each micro service starting, 10 Database connections are initiating at the back end database level. So if I am starting more than 30 microservice application, it will go to more than 300 connection.

**Confusion**

1. Is this because of any database default settings?
2. Or is this because of Tomcat problem when connecting to DB engine?

Even I tried to use connection pool tool `pgbouncer` in my database node. Then also I am getting the same problems.

If this is due to database default settings or configuration, how can I override this?

Comment: Hi Jacob. Your questions are still too chatty. Please try to refrain from "thanks in advance", "please help me", "can anyone help" and other conversational material. This is not a chat-room, and there is an expectation for neutral, technical writing.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you have an architectural problem. If each of your (different) services are dependent on a common database, then you are not operating microservices and won't get the separation benefits of microservices. In general microservices should operate their own data stores and exchange data using APIs or message buses.

Comment: So, what happens to the 11th project log-wise? In general I think this issue is to broad to give a solution. Especially with this little detail to narrow the issue down.

Answer (score 2):

A micro-service architecture is a kind of architecture in which an application is broken down into multiple independent services which are easily to understand, develop, test and are error-prone.

Now according to above definition, each independent service should have their own separate independent databases. But those services can inter-communicate for data if needed.

Each service should have a selected entities in their particular database.

If you have a common database for all those independent services, then you are violating the rule of micro-service architecture.

In this case, there is a high risk of data redundancy.

May be in your case, it is happening that services are containing duplicate version of the data and potentially using up the whole connection pool.

Better approach is to have separate database (containing only the entities specific to that service only) for separate independent service.

Clarification:

1. Explain above.
2. Maintain separate datasource hikari connection pool for all the spring boot modules/projects.

For example : Suppose you have two datasource for two modules/projects -

In application.properties.

```
## datasource for first service/module ##
datasource1.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/service1
datasource1.username=service1
datasource1.password=password1
datasource1.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource1.initial-size=15
datasource1.max-wait=20000
datasource1.max-active=20
datasource1.max-idle=20
datasource1.min-idle=5
datasource1.default-auto-commit=true

## datasource for second service/module ##
datasource2.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/service2
datasource2.username=service2
datasource2.password=password2
datasource2.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource2.initial-size=15
datasource2.max-wait=20000
datasource2.max-active=20
datasource2.max-idle=20
datasource2.min-idle=5
datasource2.default-auto-commit=true
```

Follow this links to read how to configure :

1. https://blogs.ashrithgn.com/multiple-data-source-in-spring-boot-using-spring-boot-data-starter/
2. https://www.ru-rocker.com/2018/01/28/configure-multiple-data-source-spring-boot/

Or you may need to go for Hibernate Multi-tenancy with Hikari-CP.

Comment: @Jacob Is this explanation ok ?

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I was  actually working on it. I found some other things when I am trouble shooting. I updated my findings and latest update on `updates` part on question. Can you please look edited question?

Comment: @Jacob Yeah!! I can see.

Comment: Only 1 time I started my security service. Its making 10 connection at database level. Please check the updated screenshot also from database side query.

Comment: @Jacob Are you still using common db for all microservices ?

Comment: Yes , I am still using like the same. But here I just trying to troubleshoot that initiating 10 connection is the default settings of postgresql DB engine or not. If I am running 1 micro service with this security DB, then also I can not avoid this situation. Because , Even If I am starting 1 project, its initiating 10 connection at db level.Hope that you understood what I am trying to explain here

Comment: @Jacob Then, it may happen that if your projects increases then the connection pool needs to be increased. I think it will be not feasible.

Comment: @Jacob Let me research on this. I will come up with something tomorrow.